# Writing a Show instance for (->)

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to write a generic Show instance for `(->) a b` which includes the types of `a` `b` when `(->)` is saturated? E.g.

```
*Main> :set -XFlexibleInstances
*Main> instance Show ((->) Int Int) where show f = "Int -> Int"
*Main> f = id :: Int -> Int
*Main> f
-- output: Int -> Int
```

It would be a lot of work to encode every possible combination. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't recommend this, but you could always have something like `instance (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Show (a -> b) where { show = show . typeOf }`. That is likely to be a bit more effective - especially since `Typeable` is derivable.

Comment: This works. Can you explain why you don't recommend it? Performance because type tags have to be maintained in the runtime?

Comment: @Alec Beat me to it, and your solution is far simpler. I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: AFAIK there aren't any performance penalties from doing this, as the type can be determined at compile-time and the `TypeRep` more or less optimized out. It's mainly a style thing, because if you're printing functions to the screen (for reasons other than debugging) you're probably doing something wrong, and it's nice that the compiler lets you know that.

Comment: If Alec want to paste his comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept that, because he was first and Silvio credits him as well.

Comment: This is funny:  let f a b c = a + b + c. Now show will return "Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer". Why is that?

Comment: I agree with Alec that this is just not a good idea – showing only the type is pretty useless; `show` is supposed to actually represent _values_ which for functions is just not really doable. Though, one can use specialised function types [that actually make it possible for specific applications](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.11.3/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Function.html).

Comment: @MichielBorkent Why does that surprise you? `f` is a function of three arguments.

Comment: I'm not surprised about the amount of arguments, but about the default `Integer` for `Num`.

Comment: That's a good question actually. `Typeable` only works for monomorphic instances, so `Num a => a` won't work as a `Typeable` instance. However, `Num` has [defaulting behavior](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4) and will default to `Integer` if it has to be used monomorphically.

Comment: If you print `show` (without any type signature), you'll get `() -> [Char]`, because the `a` in `Show a => a -> String` defaults to `()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if `a` and `b` are [`Typeable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html) instances.

```
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Proxy

instance (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Show (a -> b) where
    show f = show (typeRep $ a f) ++ " -> " ++ show (typeRep $ b f)
        where a :: (a' -> b') -> Proxy a'
              a _ = Proxy
              b :: (a' -> b') -> Proxy b'
              b _ = Proxy
```

With `-XScopedTypeVariables`, this becomes a bit simpler.

```
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Proxy

instance forall a b. (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Show (a -> b) where
    show f = show (typeRep $ a) ++ " -> " ++ show (typeRep $ b)
        where a :: Proxy a
              a = Proxy
              b :: Proxy b
              b = Proxy
```

Or, as Alec pointed out in the comments, you can do it in this much simpler way.

```
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Proxy

instance (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Show (a -> b) where
    show = show . typeOf
```

Comment: I object to such a `Show` instance on grounds that the output is not something I can feed back into GHCi to get back the original value. If this is just for debugging, the error message `Cannot find 'Show' instance for Int -> Bool` is just as descriptive.

Comment: I concur entirely, and I also do not recommend doing this. However, it is an answer to the question that was asked, even if said question was asked based on a pretense that we disagree with.

Comment: I understand - I'm explaining why I won't post such an answer. Also, your original instance code is buggy: `show (undefined :: (Int -> Int) -> Int)` will incorrectly output `Int -> Int -> Int`.